# how to get a html page as response in xmlhttprequest

Tags: javascript, xml, rest

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
     if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
         alert(this.responseText);
     }
};
xhttp.open("GET", "https://zbapi.herokuapp.com/", true);
xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
xhttp.send();
```

This is my code. It is returning html text but i want it to load html output.

Comment: `xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
` — You are making a GET request. You are not POSTing JSON to the URL. Why is that there?

Answer (score 0):

> It is returning html text but i want it to load html output.

`alert` expects to be passed plain text.

You need to put the HTML source code somewhere which expects HTML source code.

For example, the `innerHTML` of an Element object.

The URL you are requesting, however, includes relative URLs and has its own JS. It doesn't make much sense to request it with JS and then try to render it. You would also certainly be better off just triggering navigation with `location = "https://zbapi.herokuapp.com/"`.

Answer (score -1):

You need to parsing HTML page to JSON with some parser on the server and send parsed data to the client in JSON format. For example, Himalaya (in Node.js).

[Official repository of Himalaya](https://github.com/andrejewski/himalaya)

or use html2json ([NPM Repository](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html2json)) to parse on client